# Find longest substring that matches the end of one string and the start of the next

Tags: c

The task is to find the longest substring at the end of `string1` that is the start of `string2`.

For example, if `string1` is "monitor" and `string2` is "orange", the output must be "or".

For example, if `string1` is "bridge" and `string2` is "gear", the output must be "ge".

Unfortunately, my code gives the answer for the "bridge"/"gear" example as "rge". Please help me to find the fault in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char a[80],b[80];
    int i,j,t;
    scanf("%s",a);//input s1 example bridge
    scanf("%s",b);//input s2 example gear
    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)//traversing through first string
    {
      for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)

       if(a[i]==a[j])
       break;
       if(j==-1)
       for(t=0;b[t]!='\0';t++)

         if(a[i]==b[t])
         { 
          printf("%c",a[i]);  //output must be ge but this code gives me the output as rge
          break;
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: The requirement is unclear.

Comment: Why should it be `ge`? Last of `s1` and first of `s2`? Easy - give more informations

Comment: This is some weird code, can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: The code is supposed to look for the longest sequence of characters at the end of `string1` that is the starting sequence of `string2`, I think.  But the title of the question needs to be rewritten and shortened while the content needs to explain what’s wanted more clearly, possibly with a second example (“banana” and “anabolic” has “Ana” as the longest common subsequence, perhaps).

Comment: The indentation of the code doesn't reflect the structure of the code.  The second level `for` loop only controls the `if (a[i] == a[j]) break;` statement, though the indentation suggests you think it controls the `if (j == -1)` statement, which itself controls the next `for` loop, and that in turn controls the `if (a[i] = b[t])` statement.  Whether that's what you intended or not, I'm not sure; it doesn't look like a pattern I'd expect.  But the indentation does not reflect that control structure, which makes it hard for you and us to understand what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main() {
    char a[80],b[80];
    int i,j,t;
    scanf("%s",a);//input s1 example bridge
    scanf("%s",b);//input s2 example gear

    int k=0; //start with the first caracther
    int memo=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++) {
        if(a[i] == b[k]) {
            k++; //increase
            if(memo == 0) {
                memo = i; //save the start
            }
        }
        // reset the compar
        else {
            k = 0;
            i = memo + 1;
            memo = 0; 
        }
    }
    //if end with memo
    if(memo != 0) {
        for(int i=memo;i<strlen(a);i++) {
            printf("%c",a[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use `if (memo != 0) printf("%s\n", &a[memo]);` to print the common string, instead of using a loop to do so.  It's a good idea to end outputs with a newline, too, as shown.  Using `strlen()` in the condition of a loop is something to avoid.  The compiler might be obliged to call the function on each iteration, which can lead to quadratic behaviour in your algorithms.  It won't matter much here, but in bigger problems, it could.  Were I coding this, I think I'd start by finding the lengths of `a` and `b`, and I'd probably work backwards along `a`, rather than starting at the front.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `strncmp()` function to compare strings. It really facilitates the task. Here is the code, which is short, readable and easily understandable:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char a[80],b[80];
    char* pa;

    scanf("%s",a); //input s1 example bridge
    scanf("%s",b); //input s2 example gear

    // Iterate over "end substrings" of s1 (from the longest to the shortest)
    for (pa = a; *pa != '\0'; pa++)
    {
        // Compare with "start substring" of s2
        if (strncmp(pa, b, strlen(pa)) == 0)
            // Here it matches: exit from loop !
            break;
    }

    // Display the result
    if (strlen(pa) == 0)
    {
        printf("Nothing found\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Found: %s\n", pa);
    }
}
```

I may also suggest you the following very short way to go:

```
void main()
{
    char a[80],b[80];
    char* pa = a;

    scanf("%s",a); //input s1 example bridge
    scanf("%s",b); //input s2 example gear

    while (strncmp(pa, b, strlen(pa)) && (*(++pa) != '\0'));

    printf("%s", strlen(pa) == 0 ? "Nothing found" : pa);
}
```